# Can someone explain the output from running Bitcoin Core unit tests on Mac OS please?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, testing, unit-test

When I build and run the unit tests on Mac OS using the `make check` command the output contains these two summaries (images uploaded below). Why does the testsuite summary initially summarize zero tests and then later only summarize a small number of the unit tests? I checked with another Bitcoin Core Mac OS user and they get similar outputs.

[image: testsuite summary] and [image: make check output 2].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the output for all platforms at the moment, not just MacOS. To paraphrase from sipa on IRC:

- The first summary is bitcoin's own summary: because of some hackery to run unit tests in parallel, it currently shows no tests (even though they are executed).
- The second and third summary are the output from `make check` for the built-in dependencies, `secp256k1` and `univalue` respectively.